# Spring MVC Enum

Tags: spring-mvc, enums

Gostaria de uma ajuda, sou novo com Spring MVC e estou tentando enviar um valor numeral de um Enum que possuo em minha classe, mas não estou conseguindo, só é aceito o valor Nominal.

Gostaria de uma ajuda. Obrigado

Exemplo:

```
public enum TipoCliente 
{
    PessoaFisica,
    PessoaJuridica
}

class Clientes
{
@Column(nullable = false)
private TipoCliente tipoCliente;

//getters e setters
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/salvar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String salvar(Clientes cliente)
{
  clientesDAO.save(cliente);
}

<input type="text" name="tipoCliente" value="0"> <- Não aceita
<input type="text" name="tipoCliente" value="PessoaFisica"> <- Aceita
```

Answer (score 1):

Não aceita mesmo.
Você está tentando passar um valor que não é correspondente ao tipo de dados que declarou.
Se você estivesse usando `private Integer tipoCliente` seria possível passar o valor que deseja uma vez que é possível fazer conversão de "0" para um Integer.
Enums são muito mais poderosos do que o uso rotineiro, [dá uma olhada](http://www.devmedia.com.br/tipos-enum-no-java/25729) pra entender um pouco melhor.

Comment: Quanto a isso eu entendi, mas o que realmente gostaria de saber é se não existe nenhuma annotation como em JPA para receber esse enum numeral? Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
 private TipoCliente tipoCliente;`    Mas recomendo utilizar com cuidado esta abordagem pois ficara "preso" à ordem da enumeração e outros tipos podem aparecer complicando a manutenção do código futuramente.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tenho um enum de TipoPessoa que utilizo da forma abaixo. Detalhe que na classe de entidade, anoto o atributo com @Convert(converter = TipoPessoaConverter), ficando assim:

```
@Convert(converter = TipoPessoaConverter)
private TipoPessoa tipoPessa;

import java.util.stream.Stream;    
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;    
import lombok.Getter;

public enum TipoPessoa {

    PESSOA_FISICA("0"),
    PESSOA_JURIDICA("1");

    private final @Getter
    String code;

    /**
     * @param code
     */
    private TipoPessoa(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public static TipoPessoa getFromCode(String code) {
        return Stream.of(TipoPessoa.values())
                .filter(t -> t.getCode().equals(code))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Converter
    public static class TipoPessoaConverter implements AttributeConverter<TipoPessoa, String> {

        @Override
        public String convertToDatabaseColumn(TipoPessoa attribute) {
            return attribute.getCode();
        }

        @Override
        public TipoPessoa convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
            return TipoPessoa.getFromCode(dbData);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar assim também

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```